# What is the purpose of consolidate?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node.JS now, and the tutorial that I'm reading uses Express and Swig with Consolidate. But I didn't understand why I should use Consolidate. What is its purpose?

Sorry if it sounds a wide question, but I didn't understand the explanation on Consolidate repository (maybe because I'm not fluent in english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidate lets you use a variety of template engines without changing the interface to the developer. In this case it isn't strictly necessary, but it might be useful because you could easily switch to a different the plating library later.

Consolidate is essentially another layer on top of the template engine so the code isn't directly linked tone engine, but rather has a level in between to remove that tight link.